# Where does GitHub store my code and files?

Tags: github, storage

I have tried to found out, where does [GitHub](https://github.com/) store the code and files I commit? After a lot of search I found only that it is stored in the Cloud. This is too broad for me. I don't have (or don't know) the method, how to found exact answer.

Where does GitHub store my code and other data I commit? What is the hosting of GitHub?

Comment: GitHub uses [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)).

Comment: @Diti : Yes, I see, that is okay, but where does GitHub store files, that I commit?

Comment: @plaidshirt Did you find any answer. I have the same question. Where does Github stores all the milions of repositories and billions of files? Everyone here is telling how it works. I want to know where it stores such a huge amount of data?

Comment: @theleancoder : I have no exact answer yet, where(in which locations) and how it stores data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming or even a programming tool as defined by the help center. This is a question for GitHub the company to answer, should they see fit.

Comment: @TylerH debatable. I work in non-US aerospace, and because of ITAR regulations we have a strong incentive to stay away from cloud services where one has no control over whether the data is physically stored in the US. This definitely influences the decision of whether to go for GitHub, or self-host GitLab on-premises or similar. When we made the decision over a year ago, I could not get a clear answer on this from GitHub, so we went with GitLab.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis That sounds like a legal compliance question, which, again, is not on-topic here.

Comment: [Spokes is the replication system for the file servers where we store over 38 million Git repositories and over 36 million gists](https://github.blog/2016-09-07-building-resilience-in-spokes/). It keeps at least three copies of every repository and every gist so that we can provide durable, highly available access to content even when servers and networks fail. Spokes uses a combination of Git and rsync to replicate, repair, and rebalance repositories.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Main servers are in the US based on my observations.
git pull from San Francisco based server is lightning fast while Australian servers are significantly noticeably slower.
Possibly some additional regional hubs too.

They were at some point hosted with racksapace, no idea if still are or not.
https://www.quora.com/How-many-physical-virtual-servers-does-GitHub-have

Answer (score 8):

Currently Github seems to have its own datacenters in the USA: Northern Virginia and Seattle. https://github.blog/2017-10-12-evolution-of-our-data-centers/

Answer (score 0):

Github uses Git which can be seen as an object data storage. In this storage, files and directories are stored as git trees and blobs. 
You may want to read about git internal to understand its architecture.

In addition, Github uses ElasticSearch as a primary software stack for indexing more than 8 million repositories, allowing full-text search on source code, issues, users...
You may want to read this article
https://www.elastic.co/use-cases/github

Comment: But where are these storages physically located?

Comment: Then your question should be where Github is hosted. It may use AWS, Azure, Rackspace or even its own datacenters located in many cities. But it's an off-topic question.

Comment: they're self hosted on githubs "bare metal cloud" https://githubengineering.com/githubs-metal-cloud/

Answer (score -1):

GitHub is just a wrapper web service over [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) technology.

Just like any other version control system, Git stores your committed files under a directory on the server like `github/users/username/repositoryname`. Under this directory there are the most updated files which are exact copy of your local clone.

To see in more detail you can setup your own Git server:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

or you can install a clone script of GitHub like Gogs:
https://gogs.io

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't specific enough. I would like to know where are GitHub servers located.

Comment: Where are GitHub servers physically located? Like California, Mountain View?

Comment: Yes and is it possible to make sure where are files located?

Comment: But this is an off-topic question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Git is a “version control system.
Version control systems keep  revisions to code straight, and store the modifications in a central repository.
How Git stores the files ?
Well here is some reference material :

1) http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/17/how-git-stores-your-data.html

2) Git internals pdf : https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf