# Harddrive with github repo destroyed, how to reconnect?

Tags: git, github

Working on a school project and had my git init and branch connected to my d: drive but it got fried when the electricity cut a few days ago.

How do get my work back and continue to work from the same branch?

Comment: If you didn't push your work to a remote repo and you have no recent backup of this drive and the drive is inoperable, the repo is hosed

Comment: I have my work at my github repo and I can download it from there. But I'm not sure how to connect to my branch again so I can continue working and pushing my changes.

Comment: Clone and switch to that branch.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the problem but aren't you just wanting to clone your repo from Github back to your local PC and then checkout the branch? You'll only have the code you have pushed to Github.

Comment: I repeat what I said. Everything depends on whether you _pushed_ the branch you're looking for. If you didn't then it's gone. If you did then it's there in the clone. This word "reconnect" you keep using is totally meaningless.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Answer (score 1):

Your *GitHub* repository is stored in "the cloud" (i.e., on some server somewhere, perhaps in the Seattle or Northern Virginia area (see [Where does GitHub store my code and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39408791/1256452), which is off topic but historic and hence grandfathered into existence on StackOverflow).  Anything that has happened to your own laptop or desktop system is not relevant.

*Your own Git repository* is—or was—stored on your `D:` drive, just as you said.  That repository is presumably irrecoverable.  (There are [certain forensic data recovery techniques](https://www.google.com/search?q=forensic+data+recovery) but [you'll find they tend to be quite expensive](https://www.handyrecovery.com/how-much-does-data-recovery-cost/), and there are few guarantees here.)

The good news is this: *Every Git repository stores a full snapshot of every commit it's ever had, forever (more or less).<sup>1</sup>*  The bad news is this: The *GitHub* copy of the repository has only the commits you've *sent to it*.

This is the reason behind [matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089994/harddrive-with-github-repo-destroyed-how-to-reconnect#comment130814870_74089994).  If you ran `git push` to send the *commits* to GitHub, and they accepted the push request, your *commits* exist in your GitHub repository.  If not, they're not.

Note that I keep mentioning *commits*.  Git is not about *files*, at least not at this level, and it's not really about *branches* either: it's all about commits.  The commit is the unit of storage and transfer, when using Git.<sup>2</sup>  A *branch name*, in Git, is simply a special-purpose kind of name, with *all* names in Git serving to help you (and Git) *find* the commits.

If you *did* send your commits to GitHub, you simply need to clone the GitHub repository again.  You will get, in your *new* clone, a full copy of every commit, and—initially—*no* branches at all.  Then `git clone` will make *one* branch in your new clone, after which you can make more branches, including branches whose names match all the branches that your Git software saw in the Git repository over on GitHub.

When you go to *send* commits *to* GitHub using `git push`, you do this with:

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

(for a first-time setup for a new branch name) or simply:

```
git push
```

(after that first-time step).  This uses the named branch (first-time setup) or the current branch name (simpler, second-and-later steps) to find any commit(s) you have that your GitHub repository copy lacks.  Your Git software then packages up these commits and sends them over to GitHub, and asks them to store those commits and create (first-time push) or update (remaining pushes) a branch name in *their* repository—your GitHub repository—to remember the latest of these commits.  The *latest* commit remembers the second-latest commit.  The second-latest commit remembers the third-latest, and so on.  Git has, built in, the capacity to work *backwards* from the latest to any earlier commit, so this enables both your Git software and GitHub's Git software<sup>3</sup> to find *all* the commits, starting from the latest, on that branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>On GitHub, this is entirely true, and on your laptop, it tends to fall into the "less" category on purpose, since Git deliberately makes a lot of temporary "junk objects" as you do work, and then runs various cleanup operations at various times to clear out the "junk" commits.  You only *push* "good" commits—or at least, ones GitHub thinks are highly valuable—to GitHub, so they keep those forever, even if you accidentally push secret data to GitHub.  So if you accidentally expose sensitive data, you need to invoke GitHub's service people to scrub it, although by the time you can get them involved, billions of nanoseconds have passed and the data have probably been copied and your Bitcoins or whatever stolen.  So be careful what you push!

<sup>2</sup>A new feature, the "partial clone", deliberately "breaks" commits when cloning, so that you don't have to get a full copy of everything.  Partial clones probably have a bright future since a lot of people seem to want to lose control over their data  in the name of expediency, but at the present time I don't recommend their use in general: they have a lot of sharp edges.

<sup>3</sup>There are many different implementations *of* Git, and GitHub use one that's a bit different from the command-line Git you use on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Did a git remote add origin and git fetch --all.

Thanks for the help guys!